# Why don't negative root answer count when using derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was completing the question,

> Find $f'(2)$ if $f(x)= \sqrt{3x-2}$.

When I was calculating it as $1.5/\sqrt4$, I got the answers, $3/4$ and $-3/4$ but $-3/4$ wasn't counted in the answers. Why is that?

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is always the nonnegative square root of $x\ge0$. It's a function $\Bbb R^+ \to\Bbb R^+$. It does **not** denote the two square roots of a number. And as samjoe, I find $3/4$, not $3/2$.

Comment: Sorry. Accidentally wrote the numbers wrong

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- the real square root function $\,y = \sqrt{x}\,$ denotes the *positive* root of $\,y^2 = x\,$, by definition;
- the derivative, whenever it exists, is a function; it cannot take two different values at any point;
- $\;\sqrt{3x-2}\,$ is obviously increasing on $\,[\frac{2}{3}, \infty)\,$, so its derivative can never be negative.

Comment: Third point, is it cyclic reasoning? I mean we use derivative to prove monotonicity right? Thanks

Comment: @samjoe not necessarily. Elementary proofs of the monotonicity of the square root without using derivatives

Comment: @eepperly16 Oh right, thanks!

Comment: @samjoe Monotonicity is a far more elementary property than differentiability, and doesn't require differentiability to define or prove.

Comment: @dxiv very well, thanks for explanation +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The square root is commonly taken to be a function $\sqrt{\cdot}$ such that
$$ \sqrt{\cdot}: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty) $$
meaning that we take the non-negative square root.

Unfortunately this nuance isn't always clarified in texts but knowing now is better than never.